# Как вставить переменную из JS в html?

Tags: javascript, html, google-spreadsheet

Как вставить в `<style>` переменную `option` из функции job ? P.S. Это html верстка сайдбара гугл таблиц

```
<select>\n${option}\n</select>

<script>
  function job() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('База данных');
  var data = sheet.getRange('B3:B').getValues();
  var options = data.map(x=>`\t<option value="${x[0]}>${x[0]}</option>`).join('\n')
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Вопрос не совсем понятен. Функция `job()` ничего не возвращает. Что значит "вставить переменную"? Указать там ее имя? Или указать там значение переменной `options`? Хотя оба варианта не имеют никакого значения, т.к. просто имя переменной или некая константа - все суть ошибка для `<style>`.

Comment: И в функции `job()` нет переменной `option`...

Comment: @ksa в переменной options формируются option для <select>. Как передать в <select> эти опции из переменной options

Comment: мой ответ ниже дает ответ на твой вопрос? Там у тебя в коде есть не закрытые кавычки `"`. В моем ответе это устранено.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вангую, возможно нужно вот такое...

```js
job()
function job() {
  //const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  //const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('База данных');
  //var data = sheet.getRange('B3:B').getValues();
  var data = [
    [1],
    [2],
    [3],
    [4],
  ]
  var options = data.map(x => `\t<option value="${x[0]}">${x[0]}</option>`).join('\n')
  document.querySelector('select').innerHTML = options
}
```

```html
<select></select>
```